# How to remove woodchucks and rabbits from under my shed?

Tags: pests, rabbits

There are woodchucks and/or rabbits living under my shed.  How can I make them find a new home?

I'm in Massachusetts where it is illegal to trap them or to catch & relocate them.

I've tried used cat litter and flooding with the hose, but failed.

Comment: It it illegal in every case or are there exceptions e.g. where humans are at risk? E.g. from a structurally damaged building? And what if you use a licensed professional to relocate them?

Comment: Seems like it's not illegal to trap them. Other controls are also possible... http://www.mass.gov/eea/agencies/dfg/dfw/fish-wildlife-plants/mammals/preventing-damage-woodchucks.html Relocation is not allowed, because nobody else wants them, and it's often a death sentence for many animals.  Borrow a terrier - some are excellent vermin catchers.  They will be killed, but I assume you don't mind as you were trying to drown them.

Answer (score 5):

Some hunting stores will sell fox or coyote urine. I didn't believe it either but for a startling price you can buy a  little squeeze bottle.  The smell makes them think a predator is in the neighbourhood and they may move along.

If they do you can backfill the hole with gravel and top with a plug of chicken wire.

This is not a guaranteed solution but you have limited options.

Answer (score 3):

Have a dog that likes to hunt come and visit for a while. Check for a local falconer or bowhunter too. Hunting season appears to be closed for deer season, but will then be open through February on rabbits, year-round on groundhogs (and what dogs do by themselves does not fall under the jurisdiction of the DFW.)

http://www.mass.gov/eea/agencies/dfg/dfw/laws-regulations/plain-lang-sum/hunting-of-cottontail-rabbit-snowshoe-hare-and-jackra.html

http://www.mass.gov/eea/agencies/dfg/dfw/laws-regulations/plain-lang-sum/hunting-and-trapping-of-certain-mammals.html

Camphor and/or mothballs are other approaches to the "odor them out" method.